# window.onerror: url property empty when error in dynamically added script (via script tag)

Tags: javascript, events, dynamic, onerror

What I want to be able to do is to know if an error in a dynamically added script occured. That should be accomplished by inspecting the `url` property of the `onerror` event parameter.

However, when I add the event listener at the begin of the script, that is before the script tag is dynamically added, the `url` property is empty if an error inside the dynmically added script occurs.

So I tried to rebind the event after the script tag has been added like

```
document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
document.getElementById(scriptTagId).addEventListener('onerror',someErrorFunction);
```

as well as

```
scriptElement.setAttribute('onerror','someErrorFunction(event);');
document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

and also like

```
document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
window.addEventListener('onerror',someErrorFunction);
```

but to no avail. Actually, the error is only even getting caught using the first approach, that is binding the `onerror` event at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are having an issue as you are getting the script element by id. You can use a simple script loader to achieve the end result. The main difference is that it is binding to the `onerror` and `onload` properties of the script element rather than using event listenrs

### edit

I'm not having any problems with this script using `window.onerror` and binding to `onafterscriptexecute` instead of `onload`, and using `document.currentScript` to get the script tag that threw the error.

```js
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error){
  console.log('window.error', {
    message,
    source,
    lineno,
    colno,
    error,
    src: document.currentScript.src
  })
}

function loadScript(src, callback) {
  console.log('loading: ' + src)
  const script = document.createElement('script')
  script.onerror = function() {
    console.log('error loading script: ' + src)
  }
  script.onafterscriptexecute = callback
  script.src = src
  document.head.appendChild(script)
}

loadScript('http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/BLwWOb.js', function(){
  console.log('this aint gonna happen')
})

loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js', function(){
  console.log('success loaded jQuery')
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this only works if the url to the script file is wrong; however, it does not account for syntax errors in the script itself or exceptions in general.

Comment: what I needed was `document.currentScript`. Wasn't aware this existed, thanks again.